# Owl Carousel not displaying videos

Tags: jquery, css, video, carousel, owl-carousel

I have an example here: [VideoSlide Example](http://www.stalybridgeceltic.co.uk/videoslide.htm)

My problem is that nothing displays.

I've effectively copied the code from the Owl site, but I'm getting nothing displayed.

Originally, I'd encoded it in a bigger site, this is the cut down version with only that applicable to the carousel. I've got the carousel working with images, but the videos elude me, if anything, videos look like they should be simpler!

I have taken the latest Owl JS and CSS for version 2.

I have not amended the JS or CSS, it's in it's downloaded state.

I've done a code comparison with Owl page for videos and Calvin College, which also uses the Owl carousel with videos.

As far as I can see, I've done the same.

Obviously I've not.

Debbie

Answer (score 16):

owl's website on [video demo](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/video.html) actually [has a style for `.item-video`](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css)

```
.owl-carousel .item-video{height:300px}
```

Add that to your own css, and your videos will show up if you use the same markup as the video demo.

The options mentioned on the documentation **do not have any effect**, so I guess it might be a better idea for owl 2.0 to come out of beta (**2.0.0-beta.2.4** at time of this post).

```
videoWidth: false, // Default false; Type: Boolean/Number
videoHeight: false, // Default false; Type: Boolean/Number
```

Answer (score 3):

A convenient addition to visitsb's answer is the fact that most videos have a set aspect ratio (16:9).  So you can use the normal aspect ratio CSS padding trick to wrap each item-video in a fixed aspect ratio container.

Specifically, wrap the video items like this:

```
<div class="fixed-video-aspect"><div class="item-video"> ... </div></div>
```

Then add the following CSS to fix each item in 16:9:

```
.owl-carousel .fixed-video-aspect {
  position: relative;
}
.owl-carousel .fixed-video-aspect:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.owl-carousel .fixed-video-aspect > .item-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [visitsb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29166497/1057800) said, you can set thumbnails height from CSS. You'll get a nice carousel with a black background.

However, options mentionned in the documentation **only work when both are set** (from [source code](https://github.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/blob/develop/src/js/owl.video.js#L172))

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  video: true,
  videoHeight: 300, 
  videoWidth: 600
});
```

The result with the first solution is prettier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fluid width video containers to push the height rather than fixing the height with css. By doing this you can avoid any black banding and your videos will play flush with the container and will maintain perfect ratio on resize.

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
        <div class="item-video">
            <div class="owl-video" href="//videourl">
```

You will need to modify the css of the item-video so it will play nice.

```
.owl-carousel .item-video {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

Additionally you can also make the cover image fill the slide and lose that banding as well.

```
.owl-carousel .owl-video-tn {
background-size: cover !important;
}
```

The video wrapper I used was 16x9 but any fluid width wrapper will work. Here's the one I used.

```
.videoWrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

source: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Answer (score 0):

Just from quickly inspecting the console, looks like owl js is not loaded.

```
<script src="../assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Whilst you were 100% correct, that was a cut and paste error while I was copying from the Owl demo, and yes, I do feel dumb now! I've put it back at the JScript in my JS folder, and it still doesn't work. So I'm still stumped.

Answer (score 0):

**IF you want open page without server and have these errors:**

net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EM8b.jpg)

**Open file:**

owl.carousel\dist\owl.carousel.js

or

owl.carousel\dist\owl.carousel.min.js (if you use minify version on site)

**And add protocol, example:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD0iP.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I had to manually add a height to `.owl-video-wrapper` and it seems to be OK now.

Hope this helps someone in future. It is a bit weird though.